# How do reputation bonuses for associations between accounts work?

Tags: support, reputation, association, association-bonus

I've just joined super user, and I've associated my super user account with other accounts (at least one of which has >200 reputation), but my SU account still has a reputation of 1. Is it working like it should?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to associate from the side which has more than 200 rep. It's worked fine for me every time but I always initiate the association from SO. I'm not sure if there is a way to disassociate.

Comment: I believe the only way to disassociate is to email team@stackoverflow.com and humbly request it.

Comment: I was able to disassociate by myself.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: I didn't think it could be possible. How did you do it?

Answer (score 5):

From [stackoverflow blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/):

> Be sure to visit the accounts tab of
> your user page after you join, so you
> can get the +100 account association
> bonus on Super User! (Note that this
> requires at least 200 rep, so be sure
> to **initiate the association from the
> site where you have at least 200
> reputation**.)

So you shouldn't make the association from the superuser site.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had any issues ever with associating. Every time I have associated accounts, I gained +100 (100 for SO, SU, Meta, and now SuperUser).

Comment: Should I file this as a bug then?

Comment: Do you mean 100 each time? As in...your SU account started with 300, because of a 100 rep bonus from each site?

Comment: Andrew Grimm: I think your best bet would be to email team@stackoverflow.com I think there have already been more than enough people having issues with associating their accounts so that you won't have to make yet another post concerning it.

Comment: Andy: No, every time I have associated, I have only gained 100 Rep on the site I was associating. I received 300 BETWEEN SO/SF/Meta when I did the first association (100 per), and then when I associated with SU today I received +100 on SU.

Answer (score -1):

I also get 100 association bonus. In fact, I got it the first time on my stackexchange account in stack overflow. After that, everytime I sign up somwhere I got extra 100.