# Why did I get no reputation gain when I associated my accounts?

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do reputation bonuses for associations between accounts work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5909/how-do-reputation-bonuses-for-associations-between-accounts-work)

I have read everywhere that associating accounts will give me +100 rep. I've done this but I get no rep gain. I'm just trying to get 50 rep so I can make comments. Anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: You want more rep than you have earned on all three sites together?

Comment: Reading comprehension FTW.

Comment: And don't worry, a bunch of pity voters will surely come by and abuse the system to vote you up so that you can comment. *sigh*

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5909/how-do-reputation-bonuses-for-associations-between-accounts-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Additionally to the 100 rep in the associated accounts, you will get 100 rep in the "parent" account if you associate All tree ServerFault, StackOverflow and SuperUser accounts.
But this only happens if the "parent" account have at least 200 reputation (as 
TheTXI said).

Comment: Why the downvote? the answer is wrong? what's the matter with you people?

Comment: You probably got downvoted for saying the same thing I did 20 minutes later. Fastest Gun in the West wins.

Comment: Where is the answer talking about the additional 100 rep?
I only see yours. And my answer was an add-on to yours

Comment: @Disintegrator: So add on to his answer then, don't post the same answer 20 minutes afterwards. This is just common sense.

Comment: I can't edit others people answers. I though that the idea of answering questions was to give all the possible information NOT only for the one asking the question but also for the people who will read the answer 1 week, 1 month or 1 year later.
And Again I was ADDING information.

Comment: A comment to TheTXI's post would have solved the issue.

Comment: Chosen for the most complete answer.

Answer (score 9):

You will only get the 100 reputation bonus if the account you associate from has at least 200 rep.