# Is stackoveflow's karma over zealous?

Tags: discussion

I want to be a new stackoverflow user and my first question was a question dealing with logging in to stackoverflow with OpenId.  OpenId is based on hyperlinks, so in order to ask a question, I had to include more than 1 hyperlink.  When I posted, "karma" kicked in and told me I couldn't use more than 1 hyperlink.

To get around the problem, I just put a space in the protocol part of the url (eg, ht tp://example.com) to break the links, but it also makes the technical details incorrect.  It's minor, but in a small way ruins the integrity of the question.

A better solution would be to make the links not clickable in the question until the user gets enough Karma.

The original question I had that karma kicked in on was:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347896/is-it-possible-to-logon-to-stackoverflow-using-a-google-apps-account

LOL, and "karma" kicked in for this question too, saying new users can only post question every 20 minutes; try again later.  I guess I can wait, but isn't 20 minutes exessive?  And wouldn't a CAPTCHA be more fitting?

Comment: You should "Community Wiki" this before it gets closed.

Comment: +1 Case in point.  Just tried to upvote you (after following the migration from SO), but I've only got enough karma over on stackoverflow.  Seems like sharing some level of karma between site / meta.site pairs would be reasonable.

Comment: @data - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5909/how-do-reputation-bonuses-for-associations-between-accounts-work/5930#5930 - if you have 200 rep and you associate your account from the site with 200 rep, then the new site will give you a 100 rep bonus to get past all the new user limits

Comment: it's not karma, as it's never lupus

Comment: @Pollyanna That's great.  I suppose I set up my meta account too soon.  So in order to get any of the rep to transfer now, since I did the association long before I had the rep, do I have to delete my MSO acct, then recreate it?

Comment: @Pollyanna Thanks again. I just deleted all associations, then re-added.  I'm leaving the previous comment in case anyone else has a similar issue.

Answer (score 6):

What, only posting questions every 20 minutes is *excessive*? Dude, I've only posted seven questions on Stack Overflow *ever*.

Question Pumps are not well-regarded on the sites, so a mechanism to slow down posting is quite welcome, as far as I'm concerned. I wouldn't be dismayed if the restriction was raised to one question a *day*, even for everyone rather than simply new users.

Comment: Mostly agree, but one questions a day is too strong a restriction. I've seen (at helped, I think) post several decent question in one day as they get stuck, ask for help, move on, get stuck again,... To be sure, the other behavior is more common, but penalizing good beginning users is probably not going to help us much.

Comment: @mckee: okay maybe 1 per day is a bit overboard. :)

Comment: Holy cow. I fail at typing. That should be "I've seen (and helped, I think) users post"...

Comment: @Ether it isn't a maybe. Consider the following. You hit a stalling point, so you ask a question about it on SO. You move onto another project and hit another stalling point. Questions don't have to be on the same topic and so it isn't unreasonable to have more than one in a day.

Answer (score 5):

When I'm new to a stackexchange site, I'll put links in code blocks using the backquote:

`http://someurl.com/ditheringtechniques/4colordither.html`

And ask in a comment that someone with the ability to edit remove the backquotes.

I'll do the same thing when I need to use a tag that isn't already available - I'll ask in a comment.

It usually works out pretty well, and doesn't take long to get enough rep to participate more fully.

Answer (score 3):

Well, besides fighting spam, the reputation (or karma, as you call it) has the purpose of giving a quantitative value to the amount of trust the system (i.e. Stack Overflow) has in a user. For examples, new users often fail to make themselves familiar with the rules of the site. They don't read the introductory faq or even just the large box

> How to Ask
>
> **Is your question about programming?**
>
> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
>
> Provide details. Write clearly and simply.
>
> If your question is about this website, **ask it on meta** instead.

right on the "Ask a question" page. They just type anything they want to know into the question box and hit "Post"; no matter if the question actually belongs on Stack Overflow.

So the reputation is also a way to measure how familiar a user is with (the rules of) the site, and thus how likely they are to abide by the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, probably simply not linking the links but allowing them is much better than the current system (where you awkwardly get around it by putting a space in http, like you said).

For your second question see [this blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/)