# bonus your associated accounts

Tags: discussion, association-bonus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do reputation bonuses for associations between accounts work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5909/how-do-reputation-bonuses-for-associations-between-accounts-work)
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

```
You've earned a bonus for your associated accounts: +100 reputation
```

It just appeared on my page today. What's this bonus? How was it earned? I couldn't find more information about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the bonus if you have a StackExchange account with over 200 rep - and have registered with the same openid on any other StackExchange site.

From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation):

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.

You either reached the 200 mark or have registered with an additional StackExchange site (or both).